# stackoverflow like parser regex ? _em_ *bold* in php

Tags: php, regex

hello im makeing a parser in php
as you can see below it transform

`*this* _this_` to something like **this** *this*

```
$db['profile']['information'] = str_replace( "\n" , "<br/>" , $db['profile']['information']);
$db['profile']['information'] = preg_replace('/\*([^\*]+)\*/', '<strong>\1</strong>', $db['profile']['information']);
$db['profile']['information'] = preg_replace('/_([^[_]+)_/', '<em>\1</em>', $db['profile']['information']);
$db['profile']['information'] = preg_replace('/\[img\]((?:[^\[]+|\[(?!img\]))*)\[img\]/', '<img src="\1" />', $db['profile']['information']);
```

the problem is is on the img .

example i have a url `[img]123_460217980773_23232_11_*23123*_n.jpg[img]` well you know what it will parse. its epic. can anybody help me solve it ?

and thanks for your time looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: You could draw some inspiriation from the existing [PHP Markdown parser](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/). Though the regexps are a little elaborate there due to covering all sorts of edge cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regular expressions, while indeed useful in many situations, are definitely **not the right tool for manual parsing languages of structured text**, and Markdown can be counted as one of those.

If you want to use the same syntax as StackOverflow does, [use a Markdown parser like this one.](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/)

Comment: OTOH the linked class does belie the regex are unfit generalization.

Comment: well its too advance i just need the 3 things, i dont want user generate links. any ideas ?

Comment: While the answer about regex not been the correct tool is usually correct, this answer is misleading because the PHP Markdown parser *does* indeed use regex to accomplish this. This is because the original parser was written in Perl, and compatibility with the original implementation is more important such that ports such as showdown.js retain the regex than rewrite their own parsers.

Comment: @YiYang: The statement "Regex is not the right tool to parse structured languages" does not mean that regex might not be used *at all* in a parser. You will notice that the linked parser does a lot more than apply a few clever regexes.

Comment: but really guys all that i need is just that 3, is there an example a stip version php-markdown ? or maybe some good article on starting it ?

Answer (score 0):

Kos is right, if you want to develop your own parser you should use for example Finite State Machines, and the machine needs to be normalized.

This way you can develop a parser that automatically corrects basic errors (i made replacement parser for bbcode using this, much better, much less code than regex, much cleaner)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine